# Linq to Entity update Query Part II

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Ok, got my query going, up and running but it doesn't appear that I have got it working correctly!!

My query is as follows:

```
MyEnt updatefeedback = new MyEnt();

tblWeight newfeedback = (
    from weight in updatefeedback.tblWeights
    where weight.MemberId == memberid
    where weight.LocationId == locationid
    where weight.PriKey == prikeyint
    select weight).Single();

newfeedback.Feedback = feedbacktext;

updatefeedback.SaveChanges();
```

Basically, all I am trying to do is insert the no feedback text (feedbacktext) into Feedback. However, despite everything looking good and being populated, I don't believe tblWeight is actually being updated.

Any advice, greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks good and should work. Did you try the Profiler to see what is being submitted to the DB as the result of calling SaveChanges()?

Comment: I'm being a t*t Morteza...see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the profiler tip Morteza.

It was indeed working absolutely fine - I was being an idiot and re populating the radgrid's item template each time it loads...silly me.